# How to set a variable from outside of PHP tags

Tags: php

I am trying to create a website with PHP. For my header code, i have a file in includes/header.php with all the header code. So each page starts with

```
<?php
include("includes/header.php");
?>
```

This works, however I need some customization, so If I needed to add JS or something only to 1 page. This is what I am aiming for:

```
<?php
    $header_code =
    ?>
        Hi there, this is some code that can be used with a echo $header_code in the includes/header.php file.
    <?php
    ; //end of the header_code variable
?>
<?php
    include("includes/header.php");
?>
```

Than in the `header.php` file have echo `$header_code`, rather than having:

```
<?php $header_code = "This is some header code..."; ?>
```

Because there could be a lot of code in here.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be confuse with rush codes.

You can initialize your variable on top of your page like

```
<?php
    $header_code =<<<EOT
          <script src='jquery.js'> </script>
          <script src='jquery2.js'> </script>
      EOT;;

      include("includes/header.php");

 ?>
```

And inside **header.php**

```
if(!empty( $header_code))
{
     echo $header_code;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

Something like this

```php
$header_code = <<<EOT
   Hi there, this is some code that can be used with a echo $header_code in the includes/header.php file.
EOT;
```